# I need help to create automatic images slider with hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

[*enter image description here*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtxJz.png)

With next and previous button and last slider like moving forward and backwards. Please help me on this

Comment: We can't do this for you. There are hundreds of plugins already made, if you don't know how to integrate them you will have to study, otherwise you have to commission someone to do it, but SO has a different purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Slick carousel](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) or [Owl](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/)

find the documentation in above links